# Sum all of the values in Column N, EXCEPT for when a specific criteria is met in Column M

Tags: vba, excel

I need to sum up all of the values in Column_N, EXCEPT for when a specific criteria is met in Column_M.

I want to sum everything up in ColN of sheet0 except for when things like 'Equipment' and 'other' values are found in ColM of Sheet0.  Then I need to put that Sum into cell D16 of Sheet1 in a different workbook.

(The values in Column M can be in any order and are not always in the same order, so I can't just ignore the last two or three rows.)

```
Col_M        Col_N
Static       30
Plan         1850
Main         150
Switch       54.95
Equipment    24.95
Other        4.95
```

So instead of the sum of this column N being $2,114, it should only be $2,084, because Equipment and Other exist in Column M.

This is how I currently sum the column:

```
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim lAnswer As Variant
Set rng3 = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("N9", Range("N9").End(xlDown))
lAnswer = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--N9:N50000)")
wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D16").Value = lAnswer
```

I use this to pull out values for when a match occurs.  I think I need to change this logic to instead of when it matches, to when it does NOT match - but am not sure how to do that.

```
Dim range1 As Range

LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

For Each range1 In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("K9:K" & LstRw)
  If range1 = "Construction Costs NRC" Then
wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D10") = range1.Offset(0, 10)
  End If
Next

'and this 

LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row
Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each rng In Range("Y9:Y" & LstRw)
  If rng.Offset(0, 0) <> "Company" And rng.Offset(0, 0) <> "" Then
    If Not List.exists(rng.Value) Then List.Add rng.Value, Nothing

  End If
Next
```

Is there a way to better combine these two thoughts into one bit of code?

Comment: is vba really necessary: `=SUM(N:N)-SUM(SUMIFS(N:N,M:M,{"Equipment","Other"}))`

Comment: I mean, necessary, probably not.  But would be nice to have all the code and functionality be consistent througout.  also, how does this account for Sheet1 and sheet0 not being in the same workbooks.

Comment: Formulas can reference another workbook: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/08/excel-reference-another-sheet-workbook/

Comment: But in your vba use the top one and change the formula being evaluated to the formula I provided.

Comment: That is a good suggestion thank you, but it throws a "Compile error: Expected: list separator or ) ".  I have never written it out where a formula is used in a line of VBA, that was a copy of another solution from the site so I never understood it could be done that way.

Comment: please show the line as you entered it, I cannot read your screen.

Comment: Oh, I thought you could, sorry.  :)     This is the line: `lAnswer = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate("=SUM(N:N)-SUM(SUMIFS(N:N,M:M,{"Equipment","Other"}))")` and  `lAnswer = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate(=SUM(N:N)-SUM(SUMIFS(N:N,M:M,{"Equipment","Other"})))` and `lAnswer = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(N:N)-SUM(SUMIFS(N:N,M:M,{"Equipment","Other"}))")`

Comment: you need to double the `"` inside the string: `lAnswer = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate("=SUM(N:N)-SUM(SUMIFS(N:N,M:M,{""Equipment"",""Other""}))")`

Comment: That has removed the error, thank you - however the sum coming up in D16 of Sheet1 in the other workbook is coming up as zero.  In an earlier version of the attempt, I used `Set rng3 = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("N9", Range("N9").End(xlDown))` to get the range and help add -- that looks to no longer be needed with the N:N and M:M columns your way.  Any thoughts on why it is not adding up right at all?

Comment: I attempted to use just the formula, on the sheet itself, outside of the VBA example we are talking about - and even in the SUM formula, the result is still zero.  Used `=SUM(P:P)-SUM(SUMIFS(P:P,K:K,{"Static","Other"}))` (in excel outside of the VBA).  Converting the column to 'number' doesn't change the results also.

Comment: So I was able to adapt your suggestion, to this, and get an answer (yay):  `lAnswer = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate("=SUM(P9:P9999) - (SUMIF(K9:K9999,""Static IP MRC"",P9:P9999)+SUMIF(K9:K9999,""Deposit NRC"",P9:P9999))")`  however, it only works if I manually convert the column from general to Number.  The info comes in as General and not numbers so by default the formula will not work without some other kind of intervention which is not ideal.  I guess I have to figure out how to convert it via code at the time of copying it?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to adapt your suggestion, to this, and get an answer (yay):  `lAnswer = wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Evaluate("=SUM(P9:P9999) - (SUMIF(K9:K9999,""Static IP MRC"",P9:P9999)+SUMIF(K9:K9999,""Deposit NRC"",P9:P9999))")`
however, it only works if I manually convert the column from general to Number.

So I added this and it converts and works now:

`Range("P9:P9999").Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
With Selection
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
.Value = .Value
End With`

Thanks again for all your help Scott!